# Convert RTSP stream to virtual web camera

Tags: camera, streaming, webcam, rtsp, ip-camera

I am trying to use a RTSP stream from an IP camera as video input source for various applications on Windows (eg. Skype, Zoom, Microsoft Teams, etc.).

The only solution I have found so far is using "**[webcam 7](http://www.webcamxp.com/home.aspx)**", an application that fetches an RTSP stream and creates a virtual webcam driver that registers in system as webcam and that any application can then use. Unfortunately, this application often becomes unstable and might crash randomly.
Are there any alternative/better ways for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own DirectShow video capture filter (there are lots of examples - [this](http://alax.info/blog/1223) is a great one) and handle the RTSP stream inside it. This way you can implement the stability yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old question.
But you can also have look at [vlc2vcam](http://www.vlc2vcam.com/), looks promising.

Comment: only works with vlc 1.x and requires a third party webcam filter

Answer (score 1):

Try Moonware Universal Source Filter from http://netcamstudio.com. The only drawback is that it creates only video "composite" device that sends both video + audio and Skype can only see the video (I think most of applications does the same).
If I find an easy way to split that stream will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it on Ubuntu, Debian, Raspian, and Ubuntu Linux for Windows subsystems using the following method,

1. Installing required libraries, v4l2loopback-dkms and ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

2. Emulate a video device:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback card_label="Webcam Stream Name" exclusive_caps=1
```

3. Streaming from RTSP uri to the created virtual device:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i rtsp://uri -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

You can replace the '0' at the end of `/dev/video0` with the number of the available and playable video device.